# Where is this padding coming from and why are the flex boxes overlapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

so I'm teaching myself HTML and CSS from the bottom up. I just wanted to teach myself CSS Flexbox.

I wanted to make two simple columns to start with, but for some reason they are overlapping and I dont know why.

As you can see i've just stuck padding: 0 and margin: 0 in almost everything to try and get rid of it but I cant seem to fix it, so this must be a property I haven't learnt yet

***Here's the code:***

http://jsfiddle.net/58cshkzy/14/

***html:***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <html>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial scale = 1">
    <title>My Webpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="flex-item">1</div>
        <div class="flex-item">2</div>
        <div class="flex-item">3</div>
        <div class="flex-item">4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row2">
        <div class="flex-item">1</div>
        <div class="flex-item">2</div>
        <div class="flex-item">3</div>
        <div class="flex-item">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

***CSS:***

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

.flex-container {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.row2 {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: remove `margin-right: -15px;` and 
  `margin-left: -15px;` from `.row` (you use bootstrap and that the reason)

Comment: You are using bootstrap on your page and it has styles for .row class that adds margin-left and margin-right as -15px to it. Try using some other class name. You can rename it to row1. See updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ts6e0o14/

Comment: @NanditaSharma that fixed it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap is also having a class called `row` which styles are overriding your styles.

So rename the div class from row to row1 to see the effect.

Change the class name in the css file also.

```
<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="row1">
        <div class="flex-item">1</div>
        <div class="flex-item">2</div>
        <div class="flex-item">3</div>
        <div class="flex-item">4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row2">
        <div class="flex-item">1</div>
        <div class="flex-item">2</div>
        <div class="flex-item">3</div>
        <div class="flex-item">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use bootstrap so use bootstrap classes to make this `flexbox`:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

.wrap{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}


.flex-item {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">    
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 wrap">
        <div class="flex-item">1</div>
        <div class="flex-item">2</div>
        <div class="flex-item">3</div>
        <div class="flex-item">4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 wrap">
        <div class="flex-item">1</div>
        <div class="flex-item">2</div>
        <div class="flex-item">3</div>
        <div class="flex-item">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```